# jQuery - select element starting and ending with... but omit specific name

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax

I have elements generated on my board that have IDs like so "test_***_fast". The 3 stars are random numbers generated by the site.

Problem is that I want to write an action for all IDs except for test_1_fast, because this one is static and important.

I know I can't use:

```
$('[id^=test][id$=_fast]')
```

because it works for test_1_fast as well and code blow obviously doesn't work :D

```
 $('[id^=test][id$=_fast]' - '#test_1_fast')
```

So how should I put this to make it work?

Comment: Pattern matching on IDs is poor design, IMHO. Use a class.

Comment: ID is the only think I can use - I can't modify the code of what is generating content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use  **[`:not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)** for avoiding certain element

```js
$('[id^=test][id$=_fast]:not(#test_1_fast)').css('color', 'red')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<span id="test_0_fast">a</span>
<span id="test_1_fast">a</span>
<span id="test_2_fast">a</span>
```

---

or **[`not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not/)**

```js
$('[id^=test][id$=_fast]').not('#test_1_fast').css('color', 'red')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<span id="test_0_fast">a</span>
<span id="test_1_fast">a</span>
<span id="test_2_fast">a</span>
```

Comment: @'Pranav C Balan' works great, thanks. I wanted to use not, but the semicolon and dot syntax part was not yet in my head :)

Comment: @Ventricle : glad to help you :)